# Share Image Intent with custom Save To Gallery option

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I am using Android's default share intent to share an image to other apps. But I would like to add an option like `Save to Gallery` which saves that Image directly to Gallery in media or images or my app's folder.

Currently I am using the simple code to share image:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share to"));
```

When I tried WhatsApp's share button from profile picture, there is an option of "`Save To Gallery`" Option. Now, I came to know that, it is not pre-build in android. That is the manual action added by WhatsApp which somehow saves an image to specific path. On Long pressing that "`Save to gallery`" button shows that, that action is of WhatsApp's app. So that means WhatsApp has written some logic for it. It is the same default `ACTION_SEND` intent with `image/*` mime type with an additional custom action "`Save to Gallery`".

That's totally fine. I want to add that kind of logic for my app, too. I can register `<intent-filter>` which can handle this action but it will globally accept any image from any app to save to gallery.

How can I add a manual action for my sharing Intent or `<intent-filter>` activity which can be specific to my app only (visible by my app only) and serves the purpose of saving an Image to Gallery?

Comment: what was the final resolution to this question? running into a similar issue

Answer (score 7):

The following snippet does the following:
At first we are querying the system for IntentActivities, which can handle our Share-Intent. After that we build a List of LabeledIntents. Finally we add our custom share action to this list and we will present the list to the user, with the default chooser dialog.

```
public Intent getNativeShareIntent(final Context context) {
  final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
  final Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
  sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");      
  List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
  List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();

  for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
        ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
        String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;         
        final Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");      
        intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, ri.loadLabel(pm),
              ri.getIconResource()));
  }

  // TODO Implement the method getSaveToGalleryIntent, 
  // Could be a simple intent linking to activity.
  intentList.add(getSaveToGalleryIntent(context));

  Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(0),
        "Share");
  LabeledIntent[] extraIntents = intentList.toArray(new LabeledIntent[intentList.size()]);
  openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
  return openInChooser;
}

 private Intent getSaveToGalleryIntent(final Context context, final Uri imgUrl) {
     final Intent intent = new Intent(context, SaveToGalleryActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra(SaveToGalleryActivity.EXTRA_KEY_CONTENT, imgUrl);
  return new LabeledIntent(intent, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID,
        "Save to gallery",
        R.drawable.ic_save_to_gallery);
 }
```

Comment: Can we call a method(to download an image and save into Gallery) on click of save to gallery option rather than calling an activity??

Comment: You have to add an Intent. You can not directly call a method with an Intent. But you can try using e.g. a Broadcastreceiver Intent instead of calling an Activity.