# Add save as image for share intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity that parses an image url into an image view using the picasso library and I'm using the ACTION_SEND intent to share the image's url in other apps.
I want to add to the list of app that appears the option of Save as Image where I can save the image view's content as an image in the sd card.
how to do so?
this is my share code

```
public void share(View v) {

    String shareBody = "Check out my: "+infoUrl;
    String title;
    title = getString(R.string.infographics) + spinnerCountries.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,title);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share")); 
}
```

Guys, I do know how to save and image and how to store it ... I just want to know how to add the save to gallery option to the ACTION_SEND intent's list

Comment: Do you want to save the image or share the image?

Comment: i want the list to contain both options (like the dropbox menu) saving the image or sharing it's url. if that is not possible i want to save the image and share it as well

Comment: You may add custom option for sharing, see this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130096/share-image-intent-with-custom-save-to-gallery-option

Comment: what was the final approach to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the bitmap from the imageview using

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

And then save the bitmap to disk and then send it using this function

```
private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                Log.d(TAG,
                        "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
                return;
            } 
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
                fos.close();
                Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pictureFile);
final Intent emailIntent1 = new Intent(     android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
emailIntent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
emailIntent1.setType("image/png");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }  
        }

private  File getOutputMediaFile(){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this. 
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/data/"
            + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/Files"); 

    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    } 
    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
        String mImageName="MI_"+ timeStamp +".jpg";
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);  
    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: but like this i didn't add the save to gallry option

Comment: Since you're saving the bitmap to internal storage, it will automatically be available in the gallery.

Comment: What else do you want?